# Get spawned process return code from expect

Tags: shell, expect

I am looking for help in getting the return code for scp in spawned process with expect.

```
#/bin/bash
Password=1234
Expect -c "
Spawn /usr/bin/scp -r /tmp/ss sus@servername:/var/tmp/
Expect {
"*password:*" { send 
$password\r;interact}
}
Exit
"
```

Comment: Please don't use expect to feed a password into scp. It's really bad security. SSH tries to disabled scripted passwords for good reason. Use [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication) with `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`. It's much safer.

Comment: bash and expect commands are case-sensitive. `Expect`, `Spawn` and `Exit` would not work.

Comment: Those are in small and code works fine but need to have a return code on success or failure of status as getting always 0 if i print echo $?

Comment: If your real code uses lower-case characters, edit your question accordingly. It does not make sense posting code which is written differently from the actual code you are using.